# Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a .Net Core WebApi project with a controller that makes calls to a service, class library, to get data.  The service uses Entity Framework, not EFCore.  The error fails, here:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

Here is the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.'

I'm aware that this can be done and this is the preferred way of use .NetCore with EF according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> "The recommended way to use Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET Core application is to put the EF6 context and model classes in a class library project that targets the full framework. Add a reference to the class library from the ASP.NET Core project. See the sample Visual Studio solution with EF6 and ASP.NET Core projects."

This is the sample provided by Microsoft: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/data/entity-framework-6/sample

Here is my appsettings.json file:

```
    {
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Savi-   Development;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        },
        "Logging": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

Here is my startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(_ => new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddScoped<IRegionService, RegionService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Here is my project.cs file whith I think is correct.  It references the full entityframework.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Savi.Services\Savi.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\..\Savi.Services\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I dont have a project.fragment.json file.

Comment: Can you share your appsettings.json and startup.cs?

Comment: Entityframework is not supported yet in .net core

Comment: This solution has two projects, one api core the other net framework class library.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing like in the linked example and building the configuration manually instead of injecting it via constructor.

For example in the `Startup` class

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(_ => 
        new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<IRegionService, RegionService>();

    //...
}

//...rest omitted for brevity
```

Next I would suggest you review the suggestions from this answer I found by searching for the exception you stated in the context of .Net Core

[System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116150/5233410)

Which in summary

> You failed to change the Core *.csproj* file from `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>`

Causing the Entity Framework classes (in the .NET Framework class library) to be accessed by the DotNet Core version of Entity Framework and not the .NET Framework version of Entity Framework.

Your linked article also states

> ### [Reference full framework and EF6 in the ASP.NET Core project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-aspnet-core-project)
>
> Your ASP.NET Core project needs to reference .NET framework and EF6.
>   For example, the .csproj file of your ASP.NET Core project will look
>   similar to the following example (only relevant parts of the file are
>   shown).
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
>   <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
>   <AssemblyName>MVCCore</AssemblyName>
>   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
>   <PackageId>MVCCore</PackageId>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```
>
> When creating a new project, use the **ASP.NET Core Web Application
>   (.NET Framework)** template.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Creating a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application" and select "Net
   Framework" instead of "Core".  Selected "Api".
2. Created a new "RegionsController" with the same code as before.
3. Added all the references to my existing projects.
4. Added a reference to "EntityFramework" in my new "Api" project.
5. Updated all of my current projects in the solution to "Framework 4.7.2".  This has
   nothing to do with the error, but I wanted to point it out.
6. Add "Newtonsoft" to the "Api" using nuget.
7. Updated the new "Startup.cs" with the same code as before.
8. Added a connectionstring to the appsettings.json.

@Nikosi pointed out that this reference, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-aspnet-core-project, specifically said "When creating a new project, use the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template."  This is the answer.