# How to write the connection string correctly with provider name in azure function's local.settings.json file

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

**local.settings.json**

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyModel": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=True",
      "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityClient"
    }
  }
```

I can successfully retrieve the connectionString from the configurationBuilder in my azure v2 function via:

```
 config.GetConnectionString("MyModel")
```

But when I create my Entitiy Framework 6 code first context and do the first query on it I get that exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.'
```

How do I have to write my connection string correctly that Entitiy framework does not complain about an application config which anyway does not exist within an azure function project.

**UPDATE**

Maybe this is a .NET Core problem?
[System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185029/system-notsupportedexception-unable-to-determine-the-provider-name-for-provider)

My azure function v2 is running on .NET Core 2.1.
The MyContext EF is located in an .NET framework 4.6.1 class library which is used in that azure function project.

OR

is the problem that these/parts entries are missing. Is Entity framework nuget not adding all needed entries when installing in a azure function project?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by porting the code to support with DotnetCore. This issue has been discussed [`here`](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/623)

EDIT:

Can you try upgrading the entity framework core?. Because Azure Functions v2 version is supported only with  [`Entityframework Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions)

Also try to use [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7f263191-062d-49e5-92bb-f15549e0044e/how-to-use-entity-framework-6-from-azure-function-v2?forum=AzureFunctions) method if you are running in production

Comment: Porting what code to where exactly please, else I do not understand you :-)

Comment: https://dev.to/azure/using-entity-framework-with-azure-functions-50aa

Comment: Nah I can never upgrade to EF Core.